# Out of the twenty-six letters of the alphabet, how many ways can a word be made consisting of five different letters, two of which must be a and e?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Out of the twenty-six letters of the alphabet, how many ways can a word be made consisting of five different letters, two of which must be $a$ and $e$?

Since two letters must be $a$ and $e$, $^2P_2=2\cdot1=2$

The remaining three letters can be any of the remaining $24$ letters from the alphabet. $^{24}P_3=24\cdot23\cdot22=12144$

The total permutation is $^2P_2 \cdot ^{24}P_3=2\cdot12144=24288$

But the answer is $242880$, so I feel I'm misunderstanding something conceptually here.

Comment: There are 10 possibilities for where the $a$ and $e$ are in the 5-letter word. You assumed the first two letters must be $a$ and $e$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be careful in problems involving both combinations and permutations.

You only have to choose $3$ letters other than $a$ and $e$, $\binom{24}{3}$

and you need to permute all five letters together, what is the point in permuting then separately ?

Thus $\binom{24}{3}5! = 242880$